Error Installing Firebase on iOS: RPC Failed During git Clone
Issue:
I'm trying to install Firebase (v11.2.0) for an iOS Flutter project using CocoaPods. However, I'm encountering an error during the installation process.
After running pod install, the following error appears:
Analyzing dependencies
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '11.2.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
Downloading dependencies
Installing Firebase (11.2.0)

[!] Error installing Firebase
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git /var/folders/... --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch CocoaPods-11.2.0

Cloning into '/var/folders/...'
error: RPC failed; curl 18 Transferred a partial file
error: bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

What I've tried so far:
Increased the http.postBuffer size using git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000.
I’m from Turkmenistan, where many sites are restricted, so I had to use a VPN to access this platform. I’ve tried both with and without the VPN to troubleshoot the issue.
Tried clearing the CocoaPods cache and re-running pod install.
Also here is Debug Console:
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 16 in debug mode...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-RunnerTests`: (``)

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '11.2.0' defined in 'firebase_core'

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/11.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/11.2.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_8_b_d.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/11.2.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/8/b/d/FirebaseCore/11.2.0/FirebaseCore.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_8_4.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/8.0.2/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/8.0.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/8.0.1/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/8.0.2/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/8.0.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/8.0.1/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/8.0.2/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_7_9_1.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/7/9/1/FirebaseCoreInternal/11.2.0/FirebaseCoreInternal.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/8.0.2/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/8.0.2/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/7/9/1/FirebaseCoreInternal/11.2.0/FirebaseCoreInternal.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/7/9/1/FirebaseCoreInternal/11.1.0/FirebaseCoreInternal.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/7/9/1/FirebaseCoreInternal/11.0.0/FirebaseCoreInternal.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/8.0.0/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/8.0.1/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/8/4/GoogleUtilities/8.0.2/GoogleUtilities.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update

    Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
      A Firebase
      A FirebaseCore
      A FirebaseCoreInternal
      A Flutter
      A GoogleUtilities
      A firebase_core

    Downloading dependencies

    -> Installing Firebase (11.2.0)
     > Git download
     > Git download
         $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git /var/folders/vt/w4zbc71j1rv0v3fgm1q64srm0000gn/T/d20241022-7191-capw0y --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch CocoaPods-11.2.0

    [!] Error installing Firebase
    [!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git /var/folders/vt/w4zbc71j1rv0v3fgm1q64srm0000gn/T/d20241022-7191-capw0y --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch CocoaPods-11.2.0

    Cloning into '/var/folders/vt/w4zbc71j1rv0v3fgm1q64srm0000gn/T/d20241022-7191-capw0y'...
    error: RPC failed; curl 18 Transferred a partial file
    error: 6866 bytes of body are still expected
    fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
    fatal: early EOF
    fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:144:in `rescue in execute_command'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:141:in `execute_command'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-2.1/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:175:in `block in executable'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-2.1/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:107:in `block in clone'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:175:in `block in ui_sub_action'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:174:in `ui_sub_action'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-2.1/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:105:in `clone'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-2.1/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:73:in `download!'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-2.1/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:83:in `block in download'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:159:in `block in ui_action'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:158:in `ui_action'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-2.1/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:81:in `download'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:110:in `download_source'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:77:in `download_request'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:256:in `download'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:239:in `block in uncached_pod'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:266:in `in_tmpdir'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:238:in `uncached_pod'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:33:in `download_pod'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:42:in `download'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_downloader.rb:69:in `download!'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:117:in `download_source'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:67:in `install!'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:621:in `install_source_of_pod'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:539:in `block (2 levels) in install_pod_sources'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:86:in `titled_section'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:538:in `block in install_pod_sources'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:535:in `each'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:535:in `install_pod_sources'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:258:in `block in download_dependencies'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:257:in `download_dependencies'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:163:in `install!'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/bin/pod:25:in `load'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
    /Users/rovshenhojayev/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
         Cloning into '/var/folders/vt/w4zbc71j1rv0v3fgm1q64srm0000gn/T/d20241022-7191-capw0y'...
         error: RPC failed; curl 18 Transferred a partial file
         error: 6866 bytes of body are still expected
         fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
         fatal: early EOF
         fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 16.

Exited (1).


Here is ss from terminal how it's look like

Despite these attempts, I'm still facing the same error. Has anyone encountered this issue before, or have suggestions on how to resolve it (Also can do other approach if have any)?

Hi. I have the same issue and still don't understand how to fix this. Have you found any solution?

@EgorGrischenkov it's internet problem. But answer no I did not solve the issue
